# How to pass a function as parameter in java to run it multiple times

Tags: java

Sorry to ask that question I've seen that it has been asked a lot but not the way I'm think it.

My goal is to make a retry function that would loop 'n' amount of time to try to run the method I'm passing as parameter.

So in this case I want to run the function "myFunction()" but I know that sometimes the returned value is false and I want to run it until the return value is true.

That's how I would like it to run :

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    boolean did work = retry (myFunction(),5)
    if(didwork){
        System.out.println("I found my stuff");
    } else {
        System.out.println("I didn't found my stuff");
    }
}

public boolean retry (Function function, int loopTry){
    boolean success = false;
    for(int i=0 ; i<loopTry ; i++){
        success = function.run();
        if(success){
            break;
        }
    }
    return success;
}

public boolean myFunction(){
    boolean found = false;
    //do stuff
    if(stuff){
        found = true;
    }
    return found;
}
```

I know that it's not possible (at least in java 7 maybe in 8)

I've seen some answers suggesting to create an object for the specific function etc ... but that's wouldn't make the retry function generic since I would need to remake an object for each method that I would like to retry and that's not what I want.

So I would like to know if there is a "clean" way to do it (even in java 8) or not ?

Thank you

Comment: Create an interface with myFunction. Then implements one class with the stuff you want. You will need to pass an instance of this class to `retry` to call the function.

Comment: Seems like your function does not have input and have an output. Take a look at `Supplier` interface in Java 8. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html

Comment: `retry` accepts a `Function` object parameter, not a `boolean`. Does this code compile?

Comment: For Java 8, look at lambdas and [`java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) functional interfaces. For before Java 8, look at reflection.

Comment: In Java 8 you say `retry(this::myFunction)`.

Comment: Guys could you read the question and not just answer what is already written ? AxelH I know that way I'm asking if there is another way. T.J. Crowder it's an example ... if I knew what to give as parameter i wouldn't ask the question. Marko Topolnik this would only work inside the same object but the retry function is in another object it wouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `reflection` here:

E.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

  Method method = Test.class.getMethod("myFunction");

  boolean didwork = retry(method, 5);
  if (didwork) {
      System.out.println("I found my stuff");
  } else {
      System.out.println("I didn't found my stuff");
  }

}

public static boolean retry(Method method, int loopTry)
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

  boolean success = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < loopTry; i++) {
    success = (Boolean) method.invoke(null);
    if (success) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return success;
}

public static boolean myFunction() {
  boolean found = false;

  //do stuff
  if(stuff){
     found = true;
  }

  return found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was pretty close to work. I had to make these not static and give an instance of the object (in this case Test) as parameter to invoke and it  did work

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a while loop to myFunction() which "retries" inside the function. This would be just one addtional line. Maximum two or three if you define the maximum number of tries as n. In the second case you've recreated the effect of either trying until you get a true or until the number if tries is reached.

Comment: The thing is i don't want to do just a loop i want to to multiple things between each tries & I want to use this retry function for multiple function.

I'm just wondering if it's possible to avoid having multiple loops inside each of my function by creating this "retry" function